# Why was bounty not awarded automatically in this case?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, bounties

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31276463/2314308

When I wrote the answer, the bounty period still had two days to go according to the message. Yesterday it started showing the "grace period has 'x' hours left" message.

Today even after the grace period has ended, it still hasn't awarded half the bounty as per the documentation. Is there some other reason for this? The question has not received enough attention?

Comment: The system simply hasn't tried to auto-award it yet.